# Finding an invariant under Group operations

Tags: group-theory

Context: I am trying to answer [**this question**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6704/193) about solving the peg solitaire, and I already posted as an answer some code devised for treating the board

[image]

as a graph.

The algorithm in Mathematica for solving the problem I implemented there (please don't care to read the code) is a first try brute force approach which I want to refine.

One way for doing this is aborting the calculation of the branches already explored, and those symmetrically equivalent.

AFAIK, the symmetry of the problem is represented in the [Dihedral D4 group.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group)

So my problem: I have a vector with the **occupancy state** of the board

$S =\{o_1, ...,o_{33}\}$ $(o_i \in \{ True, False \})$

and I want to find a function that when applied to an occupancy state vector returns the same Real number for all eight symmetric states (and of course bijective, returning a different value for any other input).

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

For example, the following program in Mathematica calculates a bijective bilinear invariant under D4 for the easy board:

```
       x1

  x4        x2

       x3
```

>

```
bl = Times @@@ Union[Sort /@ Tuples[{x1, x2, x3, x4}, 2]];
coef = Array[a, Length@bl];

(* This is the first nuance, I've to write down the one member 
   for each symmetry class*)
base = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

f[{x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_}] := Evaluate[coef.bl];

(*This is the second problem: I calculate all members of each 
  class (in this case by rotations)*)
g[x_] := Table[RotateRight[x, i], {i, 4}];

fi = FindInstance[
        Unequal @@ (f /@ base) &&
        And @@ Equal @@@ (f /@ g /@ base)
   , coef, Integers];

-f[{x1, x2, x3, x4}] /. fi[[1]]
```

And the result is

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3^2 + x_1 x_4 + x_3 x_4 + x_4^2$

---

> f value  .......... Equivalent boards

[image]

I am sure there must be a better way ...

Comment: The easiest thing in practice is probably just to tabulate the 8 different permutations of the indices once and for all using a 7×7 array and coordinate manipulation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK! If nobody comes up with a more elegant solution I'll go that path

Comment: You might also consider relabeling vertices such that those indistinguishable up to symmetry are indexed by numbers which are either congruent mod 9 or mod 6.

Comment: @TimDuff Could you explain that a bit more, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A symmetry group acts on a set of data structures (the occupancy vectors).  **The question asks for a procedure to create group-invariant [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of those data structures.**  Here is a very general way, requiring only a [presentation of the group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) and explicit definitions of the actions of its generators.

In mathematical notation, the data structures form a set $S$, a finite group $G$ acts on it (notation: any $g\in G$ sends $s\in S$ to $s^g$), and a hash function is an injection $h:S\to\mathbb{N}$. To construct a $G$-invariant function, one usually averages (or sums) over the group. In this application it is computationally a little simpler to *minimize* over the group: that is, define

$$h^G: S\to\mathbb{N},$$
$$h^G(s) = \min\{h(s^g) | g\in G\}.$$

This is obviously $G$-invariant.  It works well for smallish groups because it requires computing $h$ for up to $|G|$ elements of $S$.

The rest is computational details, pseudocoded in *Mathematica*.

---

Let's begin by creating a way to address cells on the board--a way on which the effect of the group action is easy to compute--and storing an array of addresses of all the board cells.  Row and column coordinates are an obvious way:

```
n = 7;  k = 2; (* n by n square without the four k by k corners *)
validAddress[address[i_, j_]] := 
  (k < i <= n - k && 1 <= j <= n) || (k < j <= n - k && 1 <= i <= n);
board = Select[Flatten[Outer[address, Range[n], Range[n]]], validAddress];
```

It is convenient to define the group action via generators.  This is a [Coxeter group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), making it easy to find a pair of generators {`alpha`, `beta`} and relations:

```
apply[address[i_, j_], alpha] := address[n+1 - i, j];(* Horizontal reflection *) 
apply[address[i_, j_], beta] := address[j, i];       (* Diagonal reflection *)
apply[a_address, g_List] := Fold[apply, a, g];       (* Group composition *)
group = FoldList[Append, {}, Riffle[ConstantArray[alpha, 4], beta]];
```

These addresses have to be associated with the indexes of cells within the `board` array. The group action will be pulled back to those indexes as permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots\}$, which I store in a variable `action` indexed by the group itself:

```
indexes = Table[board[[i]] -> i, {i, 1, Length[board]}];
action[g_] := 
  action[g] = (apply[board[[#]], g] /. indexes) & /@ Range[Length[board]];
```

To hash an occupancy vector, it is natural to interpret it as a binary number.  To form a hash invariant under the group action, we need a unique representative of the hashes of each [orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers). A simple way to choose that representative is to use the one with the numerically smallest hash.

```
hash[occupancy_List] /; Length[occupancy] == Length[board] := 
  Min[FromDigits[occupancy[[action[#]]], 2] & /@ group];
```

For example:

```
hash[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
  1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}]
```

produces $1315991027$, the smallest of $\{1315991027, 1795954175, 4084234697, 4953218462, 4972379519, 6969629924, 8547732521, 8578425260\}.$  (The fact that the eight elements of `group` produce eight distinct hashes proves they are distinct group elements, something that might not have been evident until now.)

The efficiency is OK:

```
Timing[hash /@ RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10^4, Length[board]}];]
```

takes a half second (on one 3.2 GHz Xeon core).

Comment: Wonderful and to-the-point. Thank you!